# spring webclient unit test with mockito

Tags: rest, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to write a test for my controller (which has an autowired field pageModelService)

here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PageModelControllerTest {

@Mock
private PageModelService pageModelService;

@InjectMocks
private PageModelController pageModelController;

private WebTestClient client;

@Before
public void setup() {
    client = WebTestClient.bindToController(pageModelController).build();
}
}
```

I can't create the client, it tells me it can't autowire pageModelService

any idea

Comment: IMO you need spring context, try use `SpringRunner.class` with configured application context

Comment: Not working with Spring runner, moreover isn't that à bit weird to use mockito and Spring runner at the same Time ?

Comment: you can run only one runner . According to spec you cannot put the same annotation twice on the same annotated element.